# Combine two options

Tags: scala, option-type

I have two option:

```
val opt1: Option[Long] = //
val opt2: Option[Long] = //
```

I need to combine it into `opt3` such that

```
opt3 = opt1 if !opt1.isEmpty
opt3 = opt2 if opt1.isEmpty && !opt2.isEmpty
opt3 = None otherwise
```

Is there a more concise way than writing `if-else`s?

Comment: `opt1.orElse(opt2)`

Comment: `optA.orElse(optB)` or `for`